# Flex 4 AIR APP unloading module the proper way

Tags: apache-flex, module

I've been looking all over google for this but I cannot find a good answer.
I am using flex 4 and building an air app using modules (there will be plenty of modules because this is a big project).
I managed to load modules in a titlewindow that is called by popupmanager but when the titlewindow is closed the module is not unloaded (garbaged)  --  I checked this using the profiler in flasbuilder.

Here is my code, I need to know if I am going in the right direction using modules before getting to much in the project.

Thanks to all

```
Main APP: MXML

<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   xmlns:tblusersservice="services.tblusersservice.*"
                   xmlns:valueObjects="valueObjects.*"
                   xmlns:tbluserservice="services.tbluserservice.*"
                   width="100%" height="100%" applicationComplete="checkForUpdate()" preinitialize="nativeWindow.maximize();" currentState="login">

<fx:Script source="includes/_loadtracker.as"/>



<s:Panel id="panelmain" includeIn="mainmenu" left="5" width="100%" height="100%" resizeEffect="Resize" title="Main menu">

    <s:Image id="companymenu" right="15" top="130" width="118" height="93" buttonMode="true"
             click="loadmodule('mod_company', 'Company Information', 931, 446);" source="assets/company.png" useHandCursor="true"/>


</s:Panel>



</s:WindowedApplication>




_loadtracker.as:

// ActionScript file
import flash.filesystem.*;
import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.*;
import air.update.ApplicationUpdaterUI;
import air.update.events.UpdateEvent;
import mx.controls.Alert;       
import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
import spark.components.TitleWindow;
import valueObjects.*;
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;



// Open the pop-up window.
private function loadmodule(modname:String, modtitle:String, modwidth:int, modheight:int):void {
// Create a non-modal TitleWindow container.
settings.moduletoload = modname;
var titleWindow:TitleWindow=
    PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, showmodules, true) as TitleWindow;
titleWindow.title = modtitle;
titleWindow.width = modwidth;
titleWindow.height = modheight + 35;
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(titleWindow);
}





showmodules.mxml

<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="400"  creationComplete="initModule()" close="handleCloseEvent()">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.core.IVisualElement;
        import mx.events.ModuleEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        import mx.modules.IModuleInfo;
        import mx.modules.ModuleManager;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import services.tbluserservice.*;

        public var info:IModuleInfo;
        public var modclosed:Boolean = false;

        private function initModule():void {
            this.addEventListener("foobar", handleCloseEventmodule);

            info = ModuleManager.getModule("/modules/"+settings.moduletoload+".swf");
            info.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, modEventHandler);           

            info.load(null, null, null, moduleFactory);
        }

        /* Add an instance of the module's class to the display list. */        
        private function modEventHandler(e:ModuleEvent):void {

            this.addElement(info.factory.create() as IVisualElement);
        }

        // Handle the close button and Cancel button.
        public function handleCloseEvent():void {

                PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
                info.unload();
                info.release();
                info = null;

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
</s:TitleWindow>




mod_company.mxml

<s:Module xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
      xmlns:tblcompanyservice="services.tblcompanyservice.*"
      xmlns:valueObjects="valueObjects.*"
      width="931" height="446"
      creationComplete="LoadData()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getAllTblcompanyResult.token = tblcompanyService.getAllTblcompany();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Script source="../includes/_company.as"/>

<fx:Declarations>
    <tblcompanyservice:TblcompanyService id="tblcompanyService"
                                         fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                                         showBusyCursor="true"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="getTblcompanyByIDResult" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                     result="tblcompany = getTblcompanyByIDResult.lastResult as Tblcompany"/>
    <valueObjects:Tblcompany id="tblcompany"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="updateTblcompanyResult"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="getAllTblcompanyResult"/>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Label x="81" y="41" text="COMPANY NAME"/>
<s:Label x="81" y="71" text="ADDRESS"/>
<s:Label x="83" y="131" text="CITY"/>
<s:Label x="83" y="161" text="STATE"/>
<s:Label x="83" y="191" text="ZIP"/>
<s:Label x="83" y="221" text="COUNTRY"/>
<s:Label x="582" y="41" text="TELEPHONE"/>
<s:Label x="582" y="71" text="FAX"/>
<s:Label x="582" y="102" text="WATTS"/>
<s:Label x="83" y="276" text="OWNER"/>
<s:Label x="83" y="324" text="LOGO PATH"/>
<s:TextInput id="fNameTextInput" x="185" y="32" width="323" text="{tblcompany.fName}"/>
<s:TextInput id="faddressTextInput" x="185" y="62" width="256" text="{tblcompany.faddress}"/>
<s:TextInput id="faddress2TextInput" x="185" y="92" width="256" text="{tblcompany.faddress2}"/>
<s:TextInput id="fcityTextInput" x="185" y="122" width="256" text="{tblcompany.fcity}" textAlign="left"/>
<s:TextInput id="fstateTextInput" x="185" y="152" width="256" text="{tblcompany.fstate}"/>
<s:TextInput id="fzipTextInput" x="185" y="182" width="81" text="{tblcompany.fzip}"/>
<s:TextInput id="fcountryTextInput" x="185" y="212" width="256" text="{tblcompany.fcountry}"/>
<s:TextInput id="ftelTextInput" x="701" y="32" text="{tblcompany.ftel}"/>
<s:TextInput id="ffaxTextInput" x="701" y="62" text="{tblcompany.ffax}"/>
<s:TextInput id="fwattsTextInput" x="701" y="92" text="{tblcompany.fwatts}"/>
<s:TextInput id="fownerTextInput" x="185" y="266" width="418" text="{tblcompany.fowner}"/>
<s:TextInput id="flogopathTextInput" x="185" y="314" width="644" text="{tblcompany.flogopath}"/>
<s:TextInput id="fidTextInput" x="224" y="379" text="{tblcompany.fid}" visible="false"/>
<s:Button id="button" x="79" y="379" label="Save" click="button_clickHandler(event)"/>
<s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" x="158" y="242"
            creationComplete="dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event)" requestedRowCount="4">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="fid" headerText="fid"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="fName" headerText="fName"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="fowner" headerText="fowner"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="faddress" headerText="faddress"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="faddress2" headerText="faddress2"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="fcity" headerText="fcity"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="fzip" headerText="fzip"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="fstate" headerText="fstate"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="fcountry" headerText="fcountry"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="ftel" headerText="ftel"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="ffax" headerText="ffax"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="fwatts" headerText="fwatts"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="flogopath" headerText="flogopath"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="femail" headerText="femail"></s:GridColumn>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
    <s:typicalItem>
        <fx:Object faddress="faddress1" faddress2="faddress21" fcity="fcity1"
                   fcountry="fcountry1" femail="femail1" ffax="ffax1" fid="fid1"
                   flogopath="flogopath1" fName="fName1" fowner="fowner1" fstate="fstate1"
                   ftel="ftel1" fwatts="fwatts1" fzip="fzip1"></fx:Object>
    </s:typicalItem>
    <s:AsyncListView list="{getAllTblcompanyResult.lastResult}"/>
</s:DataGrid>
</s:Module>




_company.as


// ActionScript file
//import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import mx.controls.Alert;
//import mx.core.Application;
//import mx.core.mx_internal;
import services.tblcompanyservice.*;
import valueObjects.*;

protected function LoadData():void {
getTblcompanyByIDResult.token = tblcompanyService.getTblcompanyByID(parseInt("1"));
}

protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
tblcompany.fid = parseInt(fidTextInput.text);

tblcompany.fName = fNameTextInput.text;
tblcompany.fowner = fownerTextInput.text;
tblcompany.faddress = faddressTextInput.text;
tblcompany.faddress2 = faddress2TextInput.text;
tblcompany.fcity = fcityTextInput.text;
tblcompany.fzip = fzipTextInput.text;
tblcompany.fstate = fstateTextInput.text;
tblcompany.fcountry = fcountryTextInput.text;
tblcompany.ftel = ftelTextInput.text;
tblcompany.ffax = ffaxTextInput.text;
tblcompany.fwatts = fwattsTextInput.text;
tblcompany.flogopath = flogopathTextInput.text;
tblcompany.femail = "";
updateTblcompanyResult.token = tblcompanyService.updateTblcompany(tblcompany);
//Alert.show("Modifications saved");
//this.dispatchEvent(new Event("foobar", true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unloading Flex modules has [historically been problematic](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2009/08/what_we_know_about_unloading_m.html). Flex 4 and I assume 4.5 started to chip away at the underlying issues to make our lives easier.

When something in your main app maintains a reference to an object in your module, it will prevent your module from unloading. There are many ways this can happen. Flex may still cause some of these problems due to the way it works. But the major headaches have been mitigated (I'd make sure you're on Flex 4.5 though).

You're definitely wise for thinking about this now. Not the choice about whether to use modules, but making sure they are unloading.

The article I linked to is an old post from a Flex SDK developer, while some of those issues may no longer exist the concepts should be enlightening.

**Edit**

On further review, only one of the things that jumped out at me seem worth looking at:

- The script tag in your module may have the same problems that styles can introduce (also could be a red herring). The idea is that the first class that uses this script **may** be permanently associated w/the script internally by Flex. If that class is a module, it will never unload. As a test, you can try declaring the script tag in the `WindowedApplication` class as well (even though it's not being used).

The other thing I thought about was bindable variables in your view. But on further review, I can't see how those could be causing a memory leak.

Comment: I am using flex 4.6 actualy. I am new to flex also, do you see something in my code that might cause this?  Thanks

Comment: Doh, how could I forget about 4.6 (on vacation)! Perhaps there are somethings in your module you could look at (editing my answer).

Comment: I removed the script tag and included all AS in the same code. made some changes as follows

Comment: info.removeEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, modEventHandler);
    info.release();
    info.unload();
    info = null;
    this.removeAllElements();
    PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);

As you can see, I added a removeeventlistener and removeallelement.
But still not unloading properly.

Comment: The best way to resolve this with the Flex Profiler (if you have the Flash Builder "Pro" release). Otherwise, it can just be a guessing game :) It has a "loitering objects" report and you can see what classes are retaining references to your module classes.

Comment: I was reading the post on the link you provided and on 2.g-remote object, is mentionned to link data classes into the main app, how would i do this? any example. thanks

Comment: I believe the intent of #2g is to put the definition of data classes in the main application, not in the module swf. This way, if something in the app happens to be using the data class the module can still be unloaded. This doesn't seem to be your issue (your module seems to get it's own data and be self contained in that respect). Your module has some text inputs, it's possible that item #2f or item #3 are occurring. Also #2b could present a problem - he is referring to the resource bundles that Flex components use, not the ones you and I create.

Comment: one think I noticed in the profiler is that the valueobject do not get cleaned. the instances inscrease every time I reload the module. is there a way to clear it?

Comment: I finaly managed to succefully unload the modules, but the as soon as I add a remoteobject service to access data, it nevers gets garbaged and it increases on every new load of module. I have read many post and a lot of them are saying to put all remoteobjects in the main application but I did not found any example on how to do this. I am really new to flex and would really appreciate some sample code to help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is just that you're creating a new TitleWindow each time, and the TitleWindow adds an event listener to the module that is loaded through the module loader and [never removes it](http://www.developria.com/2010/08/rethinking-addeventlistener-an.html). In theory, PopupManager.removePopup should also dereference your TitleWindow each time, but, honestly, someone who would write this functionality as a global/static Class probably can't be trusted to adhere to good practice in other places, so you should probably use F3 to look through the code on PopupManager and make sure it's removing any event listeners it added and nulling the reference to your title window. Since it's a static Class, once something talks to it, if it doesn't dereference things properly they will stick around for the life of your app.

Next, you're manually creating an instance of your Module even though you already have one that's loaded. You do a few things (short of removing your event listener) to try to let go of the loader, but you never release the manually created instance. To simplify things a bit, try just adding the loaded module instead of creating an extra one.

Another suggestion is to *not* use View elements in lieu of a data store. So, instead of binding to the VO, when you get it populate your fields from it. When anything changes, update the VO based on the VO's value. This results in a bit more code, but for one thing, you always know your data is up to date. For another, the data can travel if it needs to, independently of the View. But this is one thing that could help you eliminate the possibility that bindings are holding the VO in memory.

There are also a few things you do that create sort of a faint barnyard smell around your code, and these could also be sources of the problem.  For instance, your title window subclass seems to have a reference to settings, even though you haven't given it one. This suggests settings is actually a static Class, and that you've ignored the naming convention that Classes should start with an upper case. More importantly, if you have communication going on in the back channel like this, there's no way to look at your code and determine that you don't have something going on where somehow you've given settings a reference to something that it is holding onto.

You also have what appears to be an undeclared variable, modulefactory, but I'm thinking this is probably a badly-named Class that lives in the same package as your TitleWindow (so there's no import statement for it). Quick word of advice: if you want to get help on forums, following naming conventions wil make it easier for people wanting to help you to unravel what you've done. In this case, there may places that you have "illicit" functionality sidestepping best practice OOP communication, and they're not easy to identify because of the way you name thing.

But ultimately, I think if you go down to just one copy of the module and remove the event listener, you should be able to let go of your Module, which should let you release the VO.

Comment: I have trying to include all my remoteobject in my main app instead of having them in the modules but I have not found any examples on how tomdo this. Would you be able to help me on this? Thanks

Comment: Here are a few posts that talk about refactoring from having a VO that loads its own children to using Dependency Injection Frameworks to handle this, which is a similar concepts: http://www.developria.com/2010/06/robotlegs-for-framework-beginn.html http://www.developria.com/2010/05/refactoring-with-mate.html . Here's the original http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2009/01/lazy-loading-tree-example-file-posted.html, where the service code is at least part of the Model and not the View.